# Application not installed

Tags: android

Download file already success but when install it has an error "application-not-installed"
I already use INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS permission
Install prompt already there but everytime I tried , it's always "application-not-installed" error.

```
public void Update(String apkurl){
    try {
          URL url = new URL(apkurl); 
          HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          c.setRequestMethod("GET");
          c.setDoOutput(true);
          try{
          c.connect();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
          File file = new File(PATH);
          file.mkdirs();
          File outputFile = new File(file, "prov1.apk");
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

          InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int len1 = 0; 
          while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
              fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
          } 
          fos.close();
          is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file

          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

          intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "prov1.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

          startActivity(intent);   

      } catch (IOException e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
}
```

I already read another question about this topic but still stuck. I am really thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems it could be that you already have some app with the same package name.
For example if you try to install com.something.prov1 the same package it might already exist. if that is the case than first uninstall the app

```
adb uninstall com.something.prov1
```

Comment: I am also agree with answer of Luk, there may be a issue of application installation with different signatures.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
Thank you. That's right I can't install cause the app already there. After uninstall it, I can install a new one. But, in my case, I want the app to auto update , is it possible in android? Is it possible to uninstall the old one after download the new one?

Comment: I do not know how the update works :(, I have experience in updating  data in my app, and I did it with broadcast receiver. I was listening for install/removal of new applications <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />, and I updated my list every time when a new app was installed or removed from the list.... I if find your answer please past the link here so I could read about that also, Thanks